# How to draw a continuous line chart from a csv with empty values?

Tags: d3.js

I have a CSV file containing values that are mesured at different paces.
I want to display it as a single chart with several continuous lines.

Here is a sample of the data as it is recorded:

```
"date","Value button A","Temperature room1","temperature room2","Hygrometry","CO2 room1"
2012/12/22-11:34,,21.6,,40,390.08
2012/12/22-11:35,,21.6,,40,390.08
2012/12/22-11:36,,21.6,19.7,40,390.08
2012/12/22-11:37,,21.6,,40,390.08
2012/12/22-11:38,,21.6,,40,390.08
2012/12/22-11:55,,22,,40,390.08
2012/12/22-11:56,,22,,40,390.08
2012/12/22-11:57,,22.1,19.9,39,390.08
2012/12/22-11:58,,22.1,,39,390.08
2012/12/22-12:11,,22.3,,39,390.08
2012/12/22-12:12,,22.3,,39,390.08
2012/12/22-12:13,,22.3,,39,390.08
2012/12/22-12:14,,22.3,19.8,40,390.08
2012/12/22-12:37,,22.7,,39,390.08
2012/12/22-12:38,,22.7,,39,390.08
2012/12/22-12:39,,22.7,20.2,39,390.08
```

My chart should have x-axis with dates and y-axis with values.

As you can see here, "temperature room2" values are only stored when temperature changes.

Is there a way of displaying continuous lines with this data without having to fill the empty cells of the CSV data ?

Comment: Could you process the data before displaying it, i.e. load the csv, then check for empty data and fill it in, and finally do the display?

Comment: Do you want a line for each of room1, room2, hygrometry and co2?

Comment: @boisvert: yes, I could do this but it is not my preferred way and I would like to know if it is possible otherwise.

Comment: @minikomi: yes one line for each sensor, actually there could be more sensors to display